# Remove Extra Space With custom Font in fabric js

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I am facing problem with custom font called **"Monogram Three Letters Circle"** Following is design when i create using fabric js it is 320*500 canvas.

[image]

I am trying export that canvas after scaling the image as i want it in that size. I am using following code to do that. But the problem is that text position change from it original position. Like following

```
newCanvas.toDataURL({
            format: 'png',
            quality: 1.0,
            multiplier: 5
       })
```

[image]

I think it might be due to padding with custom font. So is there anything using which i can reduce that gap as you see in first image. I have tried padding:0 but did not worked. Even size of that particular text is not scalling when i apply multiplier: 5

Comment: Is your textAlign set to center? I'm running into a similar issue.

Comment: Yes, i have created image in which it is center then i have resized it with php function